# Database or Serialization for this program?

Tags: java

I'm creating a very simple sports game simulation application. It needs to save just two things:

1. The teams and player skill sets (this should be loaded every time the program is started). This data is provided by the manufacturer (me), but can be edited. Eg: A player skill of 80 can be edited to say 90.
2. The statistics. The performances or scores of each game need to be updated in the stats database as the end user simulates/plays the games.

I have never worked with databases in Java. I have constructed the basic program using Java swing GUI. I need to decide how to store this data. Should I use serialization or should I go with the database. Kindly tell me which one would suit me (easy to implement) given the simplicity of my application.

Comment: How many entities of each kind are you going to have?

Comment: this project shall have more than one table right?

Comment: Two tables. Teams and Players.

Comment: The teams will have Players and Homeground as the entities

Comment: The players will have more attributes like name, style, matches, runs, catches, etc.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: how many teams are you going to have?  How many players are you going to have? How many games are you going to have?

Comment: I believe every small GUI would work just fine with sqlLite , right guys?

Comment: I'm going to have 9 teams. Each team has 11 players but the end user can create more players and add them to the team. As for games, unlimited. Depends on how many games the end-user simulates.

Answer (score -1):

Think the question you are inferring is if you should serialize the data before storing.  A database would be appropriate to save the player profile data and player game state data here.  While serialization is translating your data objects into a particular format to be saved.  Depending on language you are using, eg. Python is using 'Pickle', you can choose the type of object serialization to use.

In terms of databases, I would recommend a NoSQL database like Couchbase to help with storing the actual data.  Can check out a [blog](http://blog.couchbase.com/2015/september/create-unity-games-with-local-database) I wrote on creating database for games.